# reducing the number of subsets of

Tags: algorithm, subset

here the problem. Let's say we have a big set of N elements. We also have a big list of M small sets of elements and the small sets can intersect them which means they can have a number of same elements: SE (1->M).
Now our goal would be to find the minimum number of subsets of given n elements (where n < N ) which would contain the maximum number of the original small sets of elements.

For example:

```
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12) = big set with N = 12

(1 3 7 8)
(1 2 3 10 12)
(4 5 7 9)
(6 10 12)
(3 5 9 12)
(2 4 6 8)
(1 2 3 4)
```

let's say the sum of the sets must not exceed 9 elements (

then one solution would be:

```
subset1
(1   3   7 8 )
(1 2 3         10 12)
(    3 5     9    12)
subset 2
(      4 5   7   9)
(          6       10 12)
(  2   4   6   8)
(1 2 3 4)
```

Who has some hint for me?

Comment: Do you have an actual problem? If you're asking for general tips, I would say this question is too broad.

Comment: The question is very unclear. Is the problem to find the largest number of subsets such that their union is of size <= k (in your example 9)? But I really don't understand the line "Now our goal would be to find the minimum number of subsets of given n elements..."

Comment: Ok. Let's clear it with the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

One simple or you can say brute force approach that comes to my mind is, sort the small sets based on their sizes, so now our order will look something like this ->

```
(6,10,12), (1,3,7,8), (4,5,7,9), (2,4,6,8), (1,2,3,4), (3,5,9,12), (1,2,3,10,12)
```

and there total size count is = 4*5 + 3 + 5 = 28 is the size. So as our each subset size should be less than 9,

so number of buckets of subsets required = 28 / 9 = 4.

So now take 4 buckets and start inserting small sets starting from i = 0 to i = length, where length = number of small sets.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok. Let's clear it with the real problem. I have many orders from M clients who order M objects that need K elements to be produced by a machine. Each element of the objects is taken from a big set of N elements but the machine once setup can manage at the same time only "n" elements (where n < N ). The Goal is to produce the entire list of the M objects ordered by all clients with minimal change in setup of the machine. Is this clear now ? This is really important to get the real best minimum because setup of the machine is cost effective and all orders must be produced. Thanks for helping !